# IntelliJ VCS Incoming tab not showing changes (CVS)

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, cvs

IntelliJ 2016.1.2

Have successfully integrated with my CVS repository, can checkout/commit, create/apply patches just fine.

The VCS Repository & Incoming tabs (under Version Control) don't show any committed changes by my team that i don't have. I expected to click the 'Refresh' button in Incoming, then get a list of changes (similar to the Team Synchronising perspective in Eclipse), but this tab is not showing anything.

From the 'CVS Output' tab, I see that 'Update' results in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1\jre\jre\bin cvs rlog 
cvs rlog: Logging CVSROOT/Emptydir
Command finished ( 0 )
```

However, pressing the 'Update Project' button does pull down and merge all recent commits, which is fine, but i wanted to see/review what was available before deciding whether to update or not.

Any suggestions on how to fix? Or where this is a bug in IntelliJ?

Comment: Event log in idea showing anything?

Comment: 'Event Log' window shows nothing, plus the idea.log doesn't even roll. cvs.log does roll with the above.